# Repeated rows In R with different sequence

Tags: r

I managed to get my raw data in this form(in R) i.e for each combination of products(combination of 3) their respective count, but as you can see there is duplication happening, there are rows with same product but different ordering of those products, I needed a way to combine those rows irrespective of the order and add the sum(num) of those to get the combined sum. 
This is just a part of the entire data set. Help me to figure out a way to do this.

```
             pages               sum(num)
Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Büromöbel          6
Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Dekoration        14
Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Flur              30
Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Garten            18
Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Heimtextilien    100
Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Kinder            28
Badezimmer,Büromöbel,Baumarkt         16
Badezimmer,Flur,Baumarkt              40
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option using `cSplit` from `library(splitstackshape)`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', create a row id column 'rn' with the option `keep.rownames=TRUE`, `split` the 'pages' column by ',' and convert to 'long' format with `cSplit`.  Grouped by 'rn', we `sort` the 'pages' and `paste` it together, also we get the first value of 'sum.num.'.  Then, we get the `sum` of 'sum.num.' grouped by 'pages'.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
cSplit(setDT(df1, keep.rownames=TRUE), 'pages', ',', 'long')[,
   list(pages=toString(sort(pages)), sum.num.= sum.num.[1]) ,rn
   ][,list(Sum=sum(sum.num.)) , .(pages)]
 #                                 pages Sum
#1:     Badezimmer, Baumarkt, Büromöbel  22
#2:    Badezimmer, Baumarkt, Dekoration  14
#3:          Badezimmer, Baumarkt, Flur  70
#4:        Badezimmer, Baumarkt, Garten  18
#5: Badezimmer, Baumarkt, Heimtextilien 100
#6:        Badezimmer, Baumarkt, Kinder  28
```

NOTE: 'df1' from @RHertel's post.

Comment: Yeah this helps, nice package to know about, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possibility:

```
df1$pages <- as.character(df1$pages) # prevent use of factors    
df1$pages <- sapply(sapply(df1$pages,function(x) strsplit(x,",")),function(x) paste(sort(unlist(x)),collapse=',')) #split at commas, order words alphabetically, and restore the description
df1 <- aggregate(sum.num. ~ ., df1, sum) #sum over identical 'pages'
#                              pages sum.num.
#1     Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Büromöbel       22
#2    Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Dekoration       14
#3          Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Flur       70
#4        Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Garten       18
#5 Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Heimtextilien      100
#6        Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Kinder       28
```

**data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(pages = structure(1:8, 
.Label = c("Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Büromöbel", 
"Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Dekoration", "Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Flur",
"Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Garten", "Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Heimtextilien",
"Badezimmer,Baumarkt,Kinder", "Badezimmer,Büromöbel,Baumarkt",
"Badezimmer,Flur,Baumarkt"), class = "factor"), 
sum.num. = c(6L, 14L, 30L, 18L, 100L, 28L, 16L, 40L)), 
.Names = c("pages", "sum.num."), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but i am afraid i chose the other solution, as i got to know about a different package from that.

Comment: You're welcome - and thank you for your feedback. Choosing the answer that you found most helpful is perfectly alright. I'm also glad to learn new methods, and I think that the solution by @akrun is great.

Comment: Well done, this was a difficult task!
I am still thinking about a more efficient solution regarding memory "movements" (string operations are not very efficient in R especially if you "loop" over all rows with [s]apply).

Comment: Thank you, @RYoda. I agree that a non-looping solution would be preferable, but I don't see how this could be achieved in base R (the solution by akrun does not use loops, but I assume that the loops are run under the hood of the package that he uses).  Please post your solution if you find something!

Comment: @RHertel: I simply do not see (or cannot find ;-) a more elegant (and probably faster) solution then akrun's one using the package splitstackshape. Implicit looping is OK if uses kinda vectorization.