# How to create columns/variables by extracting characters from given column in R

Tags: r, for-loop

My data set looks like this:

```
                    key      date   census  
    1: 01_35004_10-14_+_M 11NOV2001 2.934397
    2: 01_35004_10-14_+_M 06JAN2002 3.028231
    3: 01_35004_10-14_+_M 07APR2002 3.180712
    4: 01_35004_10-14_+_M 02JUN2002 3.274546
    5: 01_35004_10-14_+_M 28JUL2002 3.368380
    6: 01_35004_10-14_+_M 22SEP2002 3.462214
    7: 01_35004_10-14_+_M 22DEC2002 3.614694
    8: 01_35004_10-14_+_M 16FEB2003 3.708528
    9: 01_35004_10-14_+_M 13JUL2003 3.954843
    10:01_35004_10-14_+_M 07SEP2003 4.048677
```

Certain characters within the column "key" correspond to different variables. For instance: 01 is the State, 35004 is the Zip Code, 10-14 is the Age Group, + is the Race, M is the Gender

I want to extract each of these characters to create separate variables for them (i.e. a column for state filled with 01, a column for Zip Code filled with 35004, etc)

Here is my code:

```
    Var = c("State","Zip_Code", "Age_Group", "Race", "Gender")
    for(j in Var){
    play$j = gsub("_.*$","",play$key) 
    }
```

Clearly this is not correct. I would like the loop to iterate through each observation in the "key" column and produce a variable with the extracted character associated with the variable.

Please Help

Comment: You should take a look at `?strsplit`.  I think `strsplit(key, "_")` will give you a matrix with all of your variables sorted into columns.

Comment: `cSplit(df, "key", sep = "_",direction="wide")` using `splitstackshape` library.

Comment: Is there a way to put this in a loop like a for loop where it iterativiley scans each observation and then extracts and puts into the column?

Comment: I think you already asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37469652/ You might want to look into linking your two accounts.

Comment: They work, and believe me, I much prefer them. But the way it is, I am working for a consulting group and they asked me to specifically create a function that could do such a thing. Also, because my remote computer -which i use to work on confidential stuff - does not have access to internet, I have to download packages externally and save them on the remote computer and downloading several packages for R to do tasks is very time consuming.

Comment: @Keith, I have edited my answer and provide an answer involving an implicit loop, although I think this is really not what you would want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(tidyr)
df_sep <- separate(df, key, into=c("State","Zip_Code", "Age_Group", "Race", "Gender"), sep="_")

   State Zip_Code Age_Group Race Gender      date   census
1     01    35004     10-14    +      M 11NOV2001 2.934397
2     01    35004     10-14    +      M 06JAN2002 3.028231
3     01    35004     10-14    +      M 07APR2002 3.180712
4     01    35004     10-14    +      M 02JUN2002 3.274546
5     01    35004     10-14    +      M 28JUL2002 3.368380
6     01    35004     10-14    +      M 22SEP2002 3.462214
7     01    35004     10-14    +      M 22DEC2002 3.614694
8     01    35004     10-14    +      M 16FEB2003 3.708528
9     01    35004     10-14    +      M 13JUL2003 3.954843
10    01    35004     10-14    +      M 07SEP2003 4.048677
```

**Edit**: Alright, in your comments you have made it clear that you really want to have a solution that loops through observations, which is an inefficient approach and for a good reason typically considered bad practice. Having expressed my objections, let me show you one approach:

First, we need to populate the dataframe with the columns. To use your approach, this would be:

```
Var = c("State","Zip_Code", "Age_Group", "Race", "Gender")
for(j in Var){
  df <- within(df, assign(j, NA))
}
```

However, a more efficient approach would be:

```
df[, Var]<- NA
```

Both give:

```
head(df)
                 key      date   census State Zip_Code Age_Group Race Gender
1 01_35004_10-14_+_M 11NOV2001 2.934397    NA       NA        NA   NA     NA
2 01_35004_10-14_+_M 06JAN2002 3.028231    NA       NA        NA   NA     NA
3 01_35004_10-14_+_M 07APR2002 3.180712    NA       NA        NA   NA     NA
4 01_35004_10-14_+_M 02JUN2002 3.274546    NA       NA        NA   NA     NA
5 01_35004_10-14_+_M 28JUL2002 3.368380    NA       NA        NA   NA     NA
6 01_35004_10-14_+_M 22SEP2002 3.462214    NA       NA        NA   NA     NA
```

Now, for each observation, we want to split `key` into components and fill columns 4 to 8 with the corresponding elements. This will be achieved with the following:

```
df[, Var] <- t(sapply(df$key, function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x[1]), "_"))))
```

Here, `sapply` loops through the elements of `df$key` and passes each element as argument the the function that I have defined, and collects the result in an array.

See:

```
sapply(df$key, function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x[1]), "_")))
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]    [,9]    [,10]  
[1,] "01"    "01"    "01"    "01"    "01"    "01"    "01"    "01"    "01"    "01"   
[2,] "35004" "35004" "35004" "35004" "35004" "35004" "35004" "35004" "35004" "35004"
[3,] "10-14" "10-14" "10-14" "10-14" "10-14" "10-14" "10-14" "10-14" "10-14" "10-14"
[4,] "+"     "+"     "+"     "+"     "+"     "+"     "+"     "+"     "+"     "+"    
[5,] "M"     "M"     "M"     "M"     "M"     "M"     "M"     "M"     "M"     "M"
```

Transposing it `t()` makes sure that it "fits" into the dataframe `df[, Var]`, and here you see that the results are identical:

```
identical(df[,Var], df_sep[Var])
[1] TRUE
```

I assume that some of the entries in `df$key` differ in their format, which is why you may want to check each value first. To do so, you can just embellish the function in the `sapply` call.

Comment: Awesome, man. You're the man! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just one small thing, in: "as.character(x[1])" , what does the x[1] signify? Thanks!

Comment: That is actually redundant. I think I changed the code from supplying the entire row as an argument, to only supplying the key. So, you can probably ignore it.

Comment: That is, you can ignore the `[1]`. Just use `x`.

Comment: Since I've got you here, I figured I would ask you about this: I would like to use the statement in a function in the form: f = function(x,y,z) { x[,y] = NA x[,y] = sapply(x$z, function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "_"))}

Comment: Then have the user input the there own values: f(df,var,key) to essentially create a data frame just as your code did. I want to do this because the code should be able to extract from a column from any data set depending on the users choice. The df I was using was just for practice.

Comment: However, when I create that function, then try to input the arguments in the function, I get the error : " Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , y, value = list()) : Supplied 5 columns to be assigned an empty list (which may be an empty data.table or data.frame since they are lists too). To delete multiple columns use NULL instead. To add multiple empty list columns, use list(list()).

Comment: Is there any advice or recommendation you could give me to create this "universal function" with your statement?

Comment: You should post that as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method that should get you started:

```
demogVars <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(df$key, split="_")))
names(demogVars) <- c("State", "ZipCode", "AgeGroup", "Race", "Gender")
```

Note that this requires the "key" variable to be of character type. You can easily convert this using

```
df$key <- as.character(df$key)
```

This method returns a data.frame where all of the variables are factors. Again, You can convert them to other types, such are character using the `as.` family of functions and can do it in one go if desired using `sapply`.

```
demogVars[] <- sapply(demogVars, as.character)
```

Since these datasets are arranged in the same order, you can use `cbind` to put them together:

```
df <- cbind(demogVars, df[, -1])
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="key      date   census  
01_35004_10-14_+_M 11NOV2001 2.934397
01_35004_10-14_+_M 06JAN2002 3.028231
01_35004_10-14_+_M 07APR2002 3.180712
01_35004_10-14_+_M 02JUN2002 3.274546
01_35004_10-14_+_M 28JUL2002 3.368380
01_35004_10-14_+_M 22SEP2002 3.462214
01_35004_10-14_+_M 22DEC2002 3.614694
01_35004_10-14_+_M 16FEB2003 3.708528
01_35004_10-14_+_M 13JUL2003 3.954843
01_35004_10-14_+_M 07SEP2003 4.048677", as.is=T)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll add that caveat to the answer

Comment: Thank you!!!while it works, Is there a way to put this in a loop like a for loop where it iterativiley scans each observation and then extracts and puts into the column?

Comment: Why would you want to put it in a loop that scans each observation? That will be a lot less efficient both in terms of time and memory.